# iOS Simulator slow-motion animation never ends when using UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, uiviewanimation

When I develop a custom transition between two view controller using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, and when I set the iPhone simulator in slow-motion mode (to easily debug animations), the animation completion handler is never called. This is very annoying, because transition never completes and app must be killed since UI doesn't respond.

Of course, it works very well when slow-motion are off.

An example of a simple `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` implementation:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        guard
            let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
            let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)
            else { return }

        containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
        toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: toViewController.view.bounds.width, y: 0)

        fromViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: true)
        toViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
        UIView.animateSpringly(duration: self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -fromViewController.view.bounds.width, y: 0)
            fromViewController.view.transform = .identity
        }, completion: { _ in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            fromViewController.endAppearanceTransition()
            toViewController.endAppearanceTransition()
        })
    }
```

Is it a simulator bug, or does my implementation have a problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: @AdamCarter unfortunately, the question is still unanswered.

Comment: We have 2020 and the problem still exists in iOS 13

Comment: I'm still asking myself if this comes from an iOS bug or a problem il my code...